# Setup Several IIS Servers With Same Config

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have several identical servers running 2008 R2. They do not have IIS installed. I need to setup IIS 7.5 on each server with the same configuration. Not the same sites, just the same install.

What is the best way?

*Copy/Paste with VM is not an option for me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the metabase file would probably be the easiest.  `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config`  If these servers will all be on the same network you could use the Shared Configuration feature and put the config for all the servers on a shared folder.

Comment: This wouldn't setup IIS.

Comment: Ah I missed that.  Well you're looking at either scripting an IIS install or using MDT/AIK to create a custom 2008R2 install with IIS installed.  Try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209.aspx for an example of how to install through a script.